# substring in php

Tags: php, html, substring

I've some html code

```
<p style="color:red;font-size:12px;">This economy car is great value for money and with the added benefit of air conditioning is ideal for couples and small families. A ?500 excess applies which can be waived to NIL for only <b>5.00</b> per day</p>
```

am using the following methods

```
substr($mytext,0,25);
```

and

```
$s = html_entity_decode($mytext);
$sub = substr($s, 0, 25);
```

But both of these are not working. 1st one returns an empty result and 2nd one returns the sting contains all the html codes..

Comment: and What output do you expect?

Comment: i need to get only 1st 25 characters ie "This economy car is great" html is not needed

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Make this:

```
echo (substr(strip_tags($mytext), 0, 25));
```

This strips all tags and shows you the first 25 chars of the given string.

Example: http://www.ideone.com/6TgJX

Answer (score 0):

```
 substr(strip_tags($mytext), 0, 25)
```

this wil show only first 25 characters with out displaying html

Comment: Copy and pasted from @Armin's answer...? O_o